# Is it possible to tar two different files at the same time?

Tags: linux, tar

I need to tar two different directories at the same time. Is it possible to execute two instances of tar in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

```
parallel tar -f {}.tar {} ::: directory1 directory2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

1) Use `screen`

2) Put them in background with `&` in the end of command line

3) CRON job with the same time of execution.